# Yii, + instead spaces in url

Tags: php, yii

Good day, experts! I have a trouble...
In urlManager i have path

```
'track/download/<id:\d+>/<filename:.+>' => 'track/download'
```

In view i generate link

```
CHtml::link('Download', ['track/download', 'id' => $model->id, 'filename' => $model->filename])
```

Yii generate link */download/578/Eminem+feat.+Rihanna+%E2%80%93+The+Monster.mp3*
So, in this action yii generate mp3 file and download this. The file name was include pluses instead spaces. That's right for RFC, but how to get links with the proper file names?

Comment: is not better to rename these files deleting spaces or replacing them with `_`?

Comment: no, i want to pretty names and i use regexp for valid file names.

Answer (score -1):

Use %20 instead of +.

See here : http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

Comment: There is no problem using + instead of %20. Readable URLs is important for usability.